# Is there a FAST way to export and install an app on my phone, while signing it with my own keystore?

Tags: android, signing

So, I've downloaded my own application from the market and installed it on my phone. Now, I am trying to install a temporary new version from Eclipse, but here is the message I get:

*Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.

You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!

Please execute 'adb uninstall com.applicationName' in a shell.

Launch canceled!*

Now, I really really don't want to uninstall the application, because I will lose all my data. One solution I found is to Export my application, creating new .apk, and then install it via HTC Sync (probably a different program based on what phone you have). The problem is this takes a long time to do, since I need to enter the password for the keystore each time and then wait for HTC Sync. It's a pain in the ass!

So the question is: Is there a way to make Eclipse automatically use my keystore to sign the application (quickly and automatically)? Or perhaps to replace debug keystore with my own? Or perhaps just tell it to remember the password, so I don't have to enter it every time...? Or some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't download your application from the market, so you can update it easily, would be one suggestion.

Comment: "Now, I really really don't want to uninstall the application, because I will lose all my data" I thought there was a way to do that, such that the data is not lost? I remember seeing that somewhere, I think

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, select Window --> Preferences--> Android --> Build

You can have your keystore pointed here

Comment: This doesn't work, since I've already created my keystore and its password isn't "android", amongst other settings. Quote: "However, any custom debug keystore/key must use the same keystore/key names and passwords as the default debug key (as described above)." (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the temp app's package in Eclipse. Change com.appname to com.appname2. Now you can debug as normal, and the apps will run side by side.

This isn't a signing problem, it's due to the fact that Android won't allow any 2 applications to share the same namespace.

Make sure you change the icon for the temp one or something though, otherwise it'll be annoying to tell them apart!

Comment: This is not a bad solution, but it's not quiet clean enough. R.java file will be moved to com.appname2 and all references will be lost. I'll have to do search+replace for it each time I switch between building for phone and building for market.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the obvious part where you don't download it from the market when you can get it so much easier update it right from eclipse, there is a way.

First, I recommend getting Android Studio as you can save passwords, which shortens down the time used by a few seconds. This is something you can skip.

Now, you have some options:

1. Use Google Drive, or any other cloud sync tool that allows you to upload files and download on your phone.
2. Have your phone download folder available and easily accessible from your computer, alongside the folder where the APK is stored after the signing. Simply drag the file into the downloads and run it from the phone

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the debug.keystore file with your own keystore (rename yours).

This file is located in the .android folder of your documents (at least on XP).

Edit: bah, GSree beat me to it.  His/Her answer is more user friendly than mine!

Edit 2:  Your question was specifically,

> "So the question is: Is there a way to
>   make Eclipse automatically use my
>   keystore to sign the application
>   (quickly and automatically)? Or
>   perhaps to replace debug keystore with
>   my own?"

I would suggest asking a different question if you don't like the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but adding the '-k' param to the "adb uninstall" command will keep your data and cache dirs:

```
adb uninstall [-k] <package> - remove this app package from the device
                                 ('-k' means keep the data and cache directories
```